# How to show the full string in treeview Python - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have the following code to insert words from a list of string and then show them in a threeview.

The problem is that when the string has the following form: "Hello Word!". It is only showed the first word.

Here's the code:

```
treeview_words = ttk.Treeview(frame_words_bag_tv, columns="Words", selectmode=tk.BROWSE)
treeview_words['show'] = 'headings'

words = {'word': 'Hello Word!', 'word':'Hi', 'word':'Okey'}

for w in words:
    self.view.treeview_words.insert("", "end", values=(w['word']))
```

How can i modify this to get the entry string in the treeview?

Comment: Try `values=(w['word'],)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
values=(w['word'],)
```

It worked!